# Twitter widget width > 520px workaround

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, twitter-widget

I need to somehow set the twitter widget to more than 520px width.
Does anyone know a workaround for this? I think I had some workarounds working for a while but recently they have stopped working.

The the problems are caused by the div inside the iframe with the class

```
class="root timeline ltr customisable-border  twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered"
```

It has the style

```
.timeline {
  max-width: 520px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Note the max-width property, if this is removed than it is possible to set the width to any size > 520px, but the problem is that it is impossible as far as I know to manipulate with the content inside the iframe since it is in different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a minor size increase you need you could apply a CSS 2D transform to scale it up slightly.

Comment: Thanks, this is a decent solution since I only needed it to about 650px in width.